# How to configure akka send/receive buffer size and maximum frame size

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have problem defining Akka configuration for maximum frame size and send/receive buffer size. How these are related ? Is there any rule of thumb for these configs?

I set my Akka with this settings:

```
maximum-frame-size = 5242880b
receive-buffer-size = 20971520b
send-buffer-size = 20971520b
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These settings have relevance if you use akka-remote. These settings control the underlying TCP implementation: what TCP buffers to allocate (this is a hint to the OS, most of the cases the OS will decide on its own anyway) and what is the largest remote payload that is accepted (maximum-frame-size). Messages that are larger than this limit in serialized form will be rejected and not sent. This is to avoid abusing the remoting layer for bulk data transfer as its primary purpose is being a control layer. For bulk data transfer some side-channel is recommended: akka.io (actor based TCP) or akka.stream (stream based TCP) or an HTTP service via spray or akka.http.